# Converting images to base64 within a loop before adding to jspdf - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64, jspdf

I have researched issues with the base64 conversion and jspdf function quite a bit. ( PS this is my first question on stackoverflow, please bare with any rookie mistakes ).

All seems to work fine with the below code except that the pdf is generated and saved before the loop where the images are converted to base64 and placed to the document is finished. I added a couple alerts to check timing. Would the solution be to check when the loop is finished, the images placed before continuing with the pdf function? if so, how? please help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#getdoc").click(function(){
    var doc = new jsPDF('landscape, in, legal');
    var myimages = 'img1.jpg|img2.jpg|img3.png';
    var myimgarray = myimages.split('|');

    function convertImgToBase64(url, callback, outputFormat){
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        return canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        callback(dataURL);
            canvas = null; 
    }

for(var i = 0; i < myimgarray.length; i++)
{
  icount.count = i;
  var img = new Image();
  alert(checkoutimgarray);

  img.src = '/Portals/0/repair-images/' + myimgarray[i];
  img.onload = function(){
      newData = convertImgToBase64(img);
      alert(newData);
      doc.addImage(newData, 'JPEG', (icount * 100), 10, 70, 15); // would doc be undefined here? out of scope?
  };
}

doc.setFontSize(20);
doc.text(100, 20, "This is a test to see if images will show");
doc.save('My_file.pdf');  

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function convertImgToBase64(img, outputFormat){

    // clear canvas
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    // draw image
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // get data url of output format or defaults to jpeg if not set
    return canvas.toDataURL("image/" + (outputFormat || "jpeg"));
}

var images = [];

for(var i = 0; i < myimgarray.length; i++) {        
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {
          images.push({
              base64: convertImgToBase64(this),
              width: this.width,
              height: this.height
          });

          // all images loaded
          if(images.length === myimgarray.length) {
              for(var j = 0; j < images.length; j++) {             
                  doc.addImage(images[j].base64, 'JPEG', (j * 100), 10, 70, 15);
              }    
              doc.setFontSize(20);
              doc.text(100, 20, "This is a test to see if images will show");
              doc.save('My_file.pdf');
          }
      };
      img.src = '/Portals/0/repair-images/' + myimgarray[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This definitely answers the question specifically, thanks! the thing I am having trouble with now is dynamically placing the images vertically depending on their index - this was the purpose of the icount variable * 100. say all images where 100px height, my goal was to get 100 * their index to stack them vertically in the pdf. I am now only seeing the latest image, I think, because they are being placed right on top of each other. trying to set the global var icount, then setting that to the index is not working so far. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, I have edited my post. Now you can access the images as base64 + their width and height for easy positioning.

Comment: as far as placing the image, that helps. but the last image is placed each time. for example, I added an alert, below i have 3 images, I am alerted '3' each time...

    images.push({
              base64: convertImgToBase64(this),
              width: this.width,
              height: this.height
          });
        alert(i);
        if(images.length === myimgarray.length) {

Comment: Because `i` is 3 after the loop ran through. Instead do: `console.log(images)` when `images.length === myimgarray.length` to see that the values are different and not 3 times the same.

Comment: right, I think that is what is happening at "img.src =..." as well. console shows the 3 different objects, with their correct height and width but the source image base64 are all 3 showing the last (3rd) image. Should I try setting the img.src within the loop?

Comment: Ah now I see the error. The `convertImgToBase64` refered to `img`. Since you didn't pass an `img`parameter it takes the last `img` from the outerscope. I fixed this now. Also you don' t need a callback in the `convertImgToBase64` since you are loading the images in a different part of your script so the function is sync.

Comment: Yes! awesome.. works perfectly. thanks, your answers are even better than I hoped for! I have seen some similar questions where I know that your solution here would definitely help as well.